# Fraction in a table

Tags: tables, fractions

I have this table which has a fraction in it. I don't like how it looks small and variables don't look clear. Is there a way to fix this or increase the size of the fraction or something? Thank you!!

```
\begin{table}[hbt!]
    \centering
    \caption{Bla bla bla.}
    \small
    \scalebox{1}{
    \begin{tabular}[t]{c c}
    \toprule
        $\omega_{PEG}$ [wt\%] & $\left| \frac{\mu_{40 \unit{\celsius}} - \mu_{60 \unit{\celsius}}}{40 \unit{\celsius}-60 \unit{\celsius}} \right|$\\
        \midrule
        0 & 0\\
        0 & 0\\
        \bottomrule
        
    \end{tabular}}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

Output is:
[image]

Comment: the fraction format is unconnected to the table, it is the style for inline, textstyle math. `amsmath` package provides  `\dfrac` for display style fractions

Comment: remove `\scalebox{1}{` it is just forcing an uwanted space to the left of the table

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @DavidCarlisle, you may use the `\dfrac` (displaystyle) command from `amsmath`. Another possibility uses the `mfrac` (mediumsized) command from `nccmath`. Below is a code illustrating both possibilities:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[hbt!]
        \centering
        \caption{Bla bla bla.}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c c}
        \toprule
            $\omega_{PEG}$ [wt\%] & $\left| \dfrac{\mu_{40 \unit{\celsius}} - \mu_{60 \unit{\celsius}}}{40 \unit{\celsius}-60 \unit{\celsius}} \right|$\\
            \midrule
            0 & 0\\
            0 & 0\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \vskip 2em
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c c}
        \toprule
            $\omega_{PEG}$ [wt\%] & $\left| \mfrac{\mu_{40 \unit{\celsius}} - \mu_{60 \unit{\celsius}}}{40 \unit{\celsius}-60 \unit{\celsius}} \right|$\\
            \midrule
            0 & 0\\
            0 & 0\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! how do i make this table align decimals?

Comment: @Khalid: the standard way to align decimals numbers on the decimal dot uses the `S` column type, from the `siuntx` package. In this case, when you want cells without decimals to be centred, you just have to add a pair of braces around their content.